# Simple Nivo slider images not loading on IE

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, wordpress, nivo-slider

I'm using this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-nivo-slider/

and when viewed on firefox & chrome the images load but on ie only the navigational arrows and navigation bullets show.

[here's the site](http://www.nulifestyle.com/)

edit: solved it by adding width and height to #slider

Answer (score 5, accepted):

solved it by adding width and height to #slider